# Return all list of Many2many/One2many

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have this code , I want to return the list of rubrique_ids and the list of critere_ids but it return only the last one , I have this relations :

```py
rubrique_ids = fields.Many2many('risques.rubrique', string="Rubrique", required=True) 
critere_ids = fields.One2many('risques.critere','rubrique_id',required=True, string="Critére d'évaluation")
```

and I have in function this code to return the list of rubrique_ids and the list of critere_ids for example I have(rub1{crit1,crit2},rub2{crit3,crit4,crit5},rub3{crit6,crit7})
it return in rubrique_etude : rub3 {critere_etude => crit7}

```py
rub = self.risque.rubrique_ids
    for rec in rub:
         rubriq = rec.nom_rubrique
         critere_ids = rec.critere_ids
         for obj1 in critere_ids:
            crit = obj1.nom_critere
    self.env['risque.evaluation'].create({'risque_etude': self.risque.nom_risque,
                                          'etude': [(0, 0, {
                                          'rubrique_etude': rubriq,
                                          'critere_etude':[(0, 0, {'critere_name': crit,
                                                     'critere_evaluation': 'CO'
                                                     })],
                                        })]
                        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this i fixed some issue hope this is what you want because 
your question is not clear.

```py
rub = self.risque.rubrique_ids
for rec in rub:
     rubriq = rec.nom_rubrique
     critere_ids = rec.critere_ids
     for obj1 in critere_ids:
        crit = obj1.nom_critere
        # FIX indentation so you create a risque evaluation for every critere_ids item
        self.env['risque.evaluation'].create({

                                      'risque_etude': self.risque.nom_risque,
                                      'etude': [(0, 0, {
                                              'rubrique_etude': rubriq,
                                              'critere_etude':[(0, 0, {
                                                                'critere_name': crit,
                                                                'critere_evaluation': 'CO'
                                                         })], # end of critere_etude list
                                        })] # end of edute list
                                    }) # end of create
```

Comment: I want create a one risque evaluation for all rubrique_ids : and  all critere_ids item not a risque evaluation for every critere_ids item I d'ont know if I have error